# c++ weird scope in if statement

Tags: c++, scope

When I declare anything inside an if statement it doesn't propagate out of it, moreover, if I have a variable outside, and i redeclare it inside if statements it lost it once the code ends the statement, how can I manage to globalize the scope of an if statement.

Comment: It works as designed. Declare the variable at the scope you want to use it.

Comment: What you are describing is how the language is designed. If you want to do something else, perhaps show an example of what code you want to write, and what effect it should have.

Comment: First thing to understand here is *variable scope*. The second thing to understand is *variable shadowing*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redeclaring a variable in an inner scope creates a new variable.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i = 1;

    if (true)
    {
        int i = 42;  // variable is re-declared
    } // lifetime of inner i ends here

    std::cout << i; // expected output 1  
    
}
```

You can reference a variable in an inner scope that was declared outside without re-declaring it.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i = 1;

    if (true)
    {
        i = 42;  // variable from outer scope is used
    }

    std::cout << i; // expected output 42  
    
}
```